# How to get data in Json url using PHP

Tags: php, json

So I have a URL that outputs as follows:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"IHLB7Mi__JPvvG2zLQWAg8l36UU/cElfTza4UGHG8g6mYtCKSIOXxq0\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"IHLB7Mi__JPvvG2zLQWAg8l36UU/EGw-f95GMJ7EnCAhVPMzL1JSykQ\"",
   "id": "UCxAICW_LdkfFYwTqTHHE0vg",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "107418936",
    "commentCount": "295",
    "subscriberCount": "428265",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "2270"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I use this function to get the `kind`

```
function test() {

    $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=youtube&key={key}";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $json_data = json_decode($json, true);
    echo $json_data["kind"];

}
```

But my issue is that I need to get other data including `viewCount` but I can't find a function for it..

Forgive me, I just started learning Json because i had to since YouTube API v 2 was deprecated and I had to switch to v 3.0 which relies on Json..

Thank you so much for assisting a beginner !

Comment: Let's start with the beginning, where viewCount resides in the JSON, structurally speaking?

Comment: Or even better, think at JSON as a hierarchy of objects (which is actually), and you'll find the answer how to access what you need to.

Comment: Inside  `"items": []` ? o.O

Comment: Never ever duplicate your own questions. Instead edit the [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29729439/367456) if the question you had changed (like now using JSON over XML).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in simple way

```
echo $json_data["items"][0]['statistics']["viewCount"]; //107418936
echo $json_data["items"][0]['statistics']["commentCount"];// 259
```

Comment: Appreciated!! I now figure out how to deal with the hierarchy.
Thank you !

Comment: Of course, in 4 min :)

Answer (score 2):

It will return mixed format of array and object.

you can get view count like this.

```
echo $json_data->items[0]->statistics;
echo $json_data->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked `$json_data["items"][0]['statistics']["viewCount"];`
:)

Comment: Great I forgot to see second param in `json_decode` is `true`

Comment: Thanks !! I will switch that to false because this type is more quick & easy.
Thank you :)

Comment: Just remove that false the default value is `false`